# How can I create a navigation drawer similar to the one used in the Google Camera app?

Tags: android, animation, android-camera, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a navigation drawer that looks like the one used in the Google Camera app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera)

I am pretty sure that they used the navigation drawer but I don't know how they managed to get the items in the drawer animated like that. So, how can I do that?

Another thing I like about it is that `onResume` of the camera app it shows a short preview of the items in the drawer and then hides them automatically. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

This is what it looks like when the items slide back in:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's pretty simple.

The `DrawerLayout` have a listener [`DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html)

in this listener you use the `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` to animate your views based on the `slideOffset`

probably something like (that's API14, if you want back-compatible check nine-old-android library):

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++{
   View item = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
   float viewOffset = i * (slideOffset / viewGroup.getChildCount());
   if(slideOffset > viewOffset){
       item.setTranslationX(- (slideOffset - viewOffset) * item.getWidth();
   }
}
```

I wrote the above code 100% untested and directly on StackOverflow website, there're probably a few typos and you might need to fine/tune or adjust the math. But hopefully you got the idea of it and can develop from it